# No JSON object could be decoded with tastypie

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I'm trying to test my API and I've never had this problem before. I'm getting the error: `No JSON object could be decoded`. I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help. I'm not even sure how to debug them.

This only occurs on the "POST"

Here's my API

```
from reflection.feedback.models import Feedback
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.api import Api
from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.exceptions import NotFound
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

class DjangoAuthentication(Authentication):
    """Authenticate based upon Django session"""
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        return request.user.is_authenticated()

class CommonMeta:
    authentication = DjangoAuthentication()
    authorization = Authorization()
    always_return_data = True

class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }

class FeedbackResource(ModelResource):

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = Feedback.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'feedback'
        excludes = ['created',]
        allowable_methods = ['post',]
        filtering = {
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(FeedbackResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your Python code, if you're using [cURL](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#creating-a-new-resource-post) to issue the request on Windows make sure that the JSON data is quoted with double quotes and all the double quotes in the json are escaped with a backslash.